# Compass Sprite Layout

Tags: sass, sprite

How do I pass layout into my sprites calling them like this?

```
$sprite-global : sprite-map(
    "sprites/global/*.png",
    $sprite-global-layout: smart
);
```

That `$sprite-global-layout: smart` is completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/sprite-layouts/), it should be applied like this:

```
$sprite-global-layout: smart;
$sprite-global:        sprite-map("sprites/global/*.png");
```

Comment: The sprites compile fine with this, but unfortunately the layout it's still ignored. I tried horizontal as well and that's ignored too. Is there a config.rb setting I'm missing or something?

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently the directory doesn't get appended to the name for the layout variable, so this does in fact work:

```
$global-layout: smart;
@import "sprites/global/*.png";
```

Also, there might be issues using sprite maps instead of the @import to set them up; see https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1024

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by inserting them as variables:

```
$sprites: sprite-map("sprites/*.png", $layout: vertical, $spacing:20px);
```